# Within PHP, how can I make sure a directory as public read access from the web?

Tags: php

I have a bunch of JavaScript files that I want to minify and then cache it to a file. This file is saved to a location I provide as argument.

How can I make sure that location has is accessible from the web?

What I've tried so far:

```
$test = array
(
    '/Users/www/htdocs/test/nhecos/cache/test.js',
    '/Users/www/foo.js'
);
$host = 'http://localhost/';

foreach($test as $t) {
    $url = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], $host, $t, $count);
    $perms = substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($t)), -4);
    $p = substr($perms, -1);

    if ($count > 0 && $p >= 4) 
        print $url;
    else 
        throw new \Exception(sprintf("File %s not accessible from Web!", $t));
}
```

This works most of the times but fails if, for instance, that file is in a Virtual Host directory or in a linked folder. Is there any better way?

**NOTE: my problem is ensuring that**

> "The files I generate are in a location that is known to the web
>   server and is mapped to a URL."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be accessible from the web is one thing, and to have "public read access" is another. You don't need one to do the other.

Typically "public read access" means OS-specific filesytem permissions.  Accessible from the web means:

1. It is in a directory that is known to a web server - that is, the file system location is mapped by the web server to a URL.
2. The permissions for the file (and enclosing directory) are such that the web server process can read the file (for static files), and can execute the files (for scripts that are run from a handler that runs as the same user as the web server).

So, in your case you want to make sure that:

1. The script runs as the same user as the web server - this is normally the case, but in some situations your scripts may be running as a different system user.
2. The files you *generate* are in a location that is known to the web server and is mapped to a URL.
3. Finally, the permissions of the file you have generated (especially if the user that executes your script is not the same as the web server process), has the correct permissions based on the system's layout.

On most unix-like systems, the web server runs as `www` or `apache`. On debian its `www-data`.

Generally, static files need octal permissions `644`, that is owner to `rw`, and the rest to only read. In `ls -l` listing, this is `-rw-r--r--` for files if the directory isn't owned by the server process.

For troubleshooting access permissions, the [apache wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied) has tips.

Comment: Yes, my choice of words wasn't probably the best. But how can I assure point 2? -> "The files you generate..." (since point 1 is rare, and point 3 is already taken care of)

Comment: Well ideally it should be any directory under the document root; that's easy to do at a file system level.  However, the URL may not "match" the file system hierarchy.

Comment: Indeed. The problem is the case scenario where a file is actually accessible from the web but is not under document root. An example would be my WebDav directory which is a sibling to htdocs directory.

Comment: You need to decide the value of it at runtime by prompting the user to enter the destination file system path.

Comment: humm, I see... this is for a module that will be available for third party developers. Maybe the "make sure your cache folder is accessible from the outside" message is the simplest yet best solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Typically you only ensure the 'parent' of the cache folder is writable and you don't expose the cache folder to the web. The best approach would be to integrate this into the installer script so it takes care of this and other pre-flight requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this simple check using "is_readable" can help, this below is just an example:

```
<?php
    if (is_readable('../../../www')) echo "www is readable"; 
        else echo "www is unaccessible";
    echo '<br/>';
    if (is_readable('../../htdocs')) echo "htdocs is readable"; 
        else echo "htdocs is unaccessible";
?>
```

Update to be able to check file using the specified URL (using file_get_contents or copy functions/methods from PHP):

```
<?php
    if (@copy('http://.../file.js', 'dummy.file')) echo "file is readable"; 
        else echo "file is unaccessible";
    echo '<br/>';
    if (@file_get_contents('http://.../file.js'))  echo "file is readable"; 
        else echo "file is unaccessible";
?>
```

Cheers,

Comment: well, this doesn't ensure the file is accessible from the web just that "Apache User" can read it. Apache (and PHP) can virtually read any folder or file provided its user has permissions to it.

Comment: you are right, sorry for that. How about using a php function "file_get_contents('the url here')". When it returns false, it means the specified file in the url cannot be accessed. There is also another alternative using a PHP function "copy('url source','url destination')". However, the use of this "copy" function requires us to specify a destination file (could be just a dummy file). I updated the example above. All the best   :))

Comment: This will only work if [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is enabled.

Comment: And the script would have to "guess" the url. If it failed it could either be because the folder was not web public or because the script guessed wrong.